# Iframe con PHP passing value

Tags: php, html, iframe

I don't know how to explaine exactly. I don't have a code to show.I must to do a web page with this settings. On the same page. On the left i write from keyboard the code on language PHP for example. On the right i se the result of the code PHP that i have write on the left.The only idea to do this is use iframe, but i don't know  how to do. On particular for example i load the page and all is blank. At this point i go to write on the form on the left

```
<?php
        
    for ($i=1;$i<10;$i++) {
        
        echo "<br>value of i is $i";
        
   }
        
?>

and on the form b on the right of the same page after my click on submit must appear



value of i = 1
value of i = 2
value of i = 3
value of i = 10


someone has some idea? Thx.
```

Comment: This is a site to get help with your existing code, not to help you design something that you haven't yet designed.  
If you don't have current code, nor do you know how you'd design this on paper regardless of code implementation, then you need to do [more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before posting here. 
To get you started, you can obtain this with Javascript to read the input PHP code, passing it via Ajax to PHP to be executed and return the result to the frontend.

Comment: I've try it , i don't have obtain the wanted resulted, so i 've asked...may be there is  a function that i don't know for help me.